# how to solve equation with epsilon

Tags: elementary-number-theory, regular-expressions, finite-automata

i am working on a problem for Regular expression and it resulted to this

$\epsilon + a+b + aa+ab + ba + bb$

now when i solved it further and reached here

$\epsilon + a + b + (a+b)(a+b)$
the solution is $(a+b+\epsilon)(a+b+\epsilon)$ , how to reach to this

Comment: $\epsilon = \epsilon \epsilon$ and $a+b = (a+b) + (a+b)$ and $\epsilon(a+b) = (a+b)$ and $(a+b)\epsilon = (a+b)$.

Comment: more information is required here - for example, as an algebraic quantity $(\epsilon + a +b)^{2}=\epsilon^{2}+(a+b)^{2}+2\epsilon(a+b)$

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what more info do u need @Bacon

Comment: sorry @copper.hat i m not able to understand what you are trying to say , can u please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using distributive, associative, idempotent properties, we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\epsilon + a+b + aa+ab + ba + bb &=& \epsilon + (a+b) + (a+b)(a+b) \\
&=& \epsilon + \epsilon + \epsilon(a+b) + (a+b)\epsilon+ (a+b)(a+b) \\
&=& \epsilon\epsilon + \epsilon(a+b) + (a+b)\epsilon+ (a+b)(a+b) \\
&=& (a+b+\epsilon)(a+b+\epsilon)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: how can this be true - `a+b=(a+b)+(a+b)` as mentioned in ur comment

Comment: The $+$ means union of the languages. So $L+L=L$.

Comment: can you look at this ques for once - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505301/regular-expression-for-language-containing-string-which-starts-and-ends-with-dif