# Regular expression for language containing all strings that start and end with different symbols

Tags: automata, regular-expressions, finite-automata

ques -

> Regular expression for language containing all strings that start and
>   end with different symbols

i just went through some examples where the RE for above question is `a(a+b)*b + b(a+b)*a` but i think it should be `(a(a+b)*b)* + (b(a+b)*a)*`. Am i correct or incorrect ?

Comment: thanks i think this many tags are enough, though i have added one more according to your suggestion. thanks @NormalHuman

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'for above question'?

Comment: the question in title `Regular expression for language containing all strings that start and end with different symbols` where aphabet is {a,b} @copper.hat

Comment: I see, in general it is worth repeating the title in the question, possibly paraphrased.

Comment: done with editing @copper.hat

Comment: Thanks - Brian has answered the question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost correct: not quite, because your language accepts the empty string :) The original is correct. If you used `+` (one or more) rather than outermost `*` (zero or more), then the languages denoted by the two REs (yours, with that change, and the original) are the same language.

Let's alter your RE as mentioned:$$
(a(a+b)^*b)^+ + (b(a+b)^*a)^+  \tag{1}
$$

Clearly, (the language of) (1) contains (that of) the original. To see the reverse inclusion, suppose $w$ is in the language of (1). Without loss of generality assume $w \in L((a(a+b)^*b)^+)$. Then for some $n > 0$, $w = x_1 \dots x_n$ with each $x_i \in L(a(a+b)^*b)$. But then $x_1$ begins with $a$, $x_n$ ends with $b$, and everything in between is just a string in $L((a+b)^*)$. Thus $w \in L(a(a+b)^*b)$, so it's in the language of the original RE.